# Remove repetition from if-else statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have written an `if...else` statement which uses an array `myArr` and a string `myStr` as follows:

```
If myArr.Length > 0 AndAlso myArr(0) = "-1" Then
  'Do stuff 1
ElseIf myStr= "xyz" Then
  'Do stuff 2
ElseIf myArr.Length > 0 Then
  'Do Stuff 3
Else
  'Do Nothing
End If
```

It works exactly as I need. But It looks really confusing, mostly because the array length is checked twice. There must be a clearer way to write it, but I can't think of one.

Just to clarify.... the order that each statement is executed is crucial. i.e. Stuff 1 has priority over stuff 2, which has priority over stuff 3.

Comment: +1 for a question worth thinking about before rushing in!

Comment: And +1 for both your comments for not rushing in! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to get exactly the same flow in a simpler way.

Either you're going to end up doing things different things, or doing duplicate things. eg:

```
If myArr.Length > 0 Then
   If myArr(0) = "-1" Then
      'Do stuff
   Else
      'Do stuff
   End If
ElseIf myStr= "xyz" Then
  'Do stuff
Else
  'Do Nothing
End If
```

This will cause mystr="xyz" not to happen whenn myArr(0) <> -1 whereas it may have before.

Comment: Well then. It looks like my code is staying as it is. Thanks for the considered answer!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get rid of multiple checks against `myArr.Length` by using nested `If` statements, but this makes the code less clear.

A *clear* approach (i.e. one that can be understood easily) is one that allows you to read a code fragment without having to remember the context in which the code is executed. By nesting `If` statements, more information must be kept in the readers working memory  (or *short term memory*) to deduce the meaning of he code.

Answer (score 0):

You can decompose the statements like this:

```
If myArr.Length > 0 Then
    If myArr(0) = "-1" Then
       'Do stuff
    Else
       'Do sstuff
    End If
Else
    If myyStr= "xyz" Then
        'Do stuff
    End If
End If
```

Comment: This isn't the same. In this case you'll end up doing both the myArr(0) <> -1 stuff and the myStr = "xyz"

Comment: This is different when `myArr.Length > 0 AndAlso myyStr= "xyz"`.

Comment: @Jon, I agree, this is not the same, as in original code. But, it is a bad tone and certainly unclear way to combine conditions that are logically not bounded at all. I've modified the code, can you please comment?

Comment: @Oswald, hos is it different?

Comment: @Zaur I've tried to clarify my question now, to make it clear which order the "stuff" must be done in. It needs to be stuff 1,2,3. But with your suggested method, it is stuff 1,3,2.

Comment: @Urbycoz, I see your point. Yep, in this case my code is also wrong. But what I'm trying to say, it's a really bad idea to combine logically non-related conditions. E.g. If Alex.LastName = "Mack"... Else If Sun.Shining ...

Comment: @Zaur Ok. Fair point. However, I do think there could be a similar situation where the conditions were related in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would do the trick:

```
If myArr.Length > 0 Then
   If myArr(0) = "-1" Then
      'Do stuff
   Else
      'Do stuff
   End If
ElseIf myStr= "xyz" Then
  'Do stuff
Else
  'Do Nothing
End If
```

Comment: This isn't the same. In this case you'll end up doing both the myArr(0) <> -1 stuff even if myStr = "xyz".

Comment: Yes. The order is crucial I'm afraid.

Comment: See my answer. Don't think you can change it without breaking it or making it more messy.

Comment: @JonEgerton if my eyes do not trick me... it happens to be just the same as what I have posted :)

Comment: The code is the same. But the words are not. Basically the answer seems to be "it can't be simplified".

Answer (score 0):

What you need is nested if

```
If myArr.Length > 0 Then
  'Do stuff for non zero length
    If myArr(0) = "-1" Then
       'Do stuff for -1 and you already have checked for array length
    End If 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If myArr.Length > 0 Then
  If myArr(0) = "-1" Then
    ' Stuff 1
  Else
    ' Stuff 3
  End If
ElseIf myStr = "xyz"
' Stuff 2
End If
```

... no further else needed

Comment: Thanks, but the trouble is that stuff 2 should have higher priority than stuff 3.

Comment: Quite Right, I got caught up in the mad rush to answer a question :-)